# AWS Lambda Java function invoked multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, aws-lambda

I've got an `AWS` Lambda function I've written in Java (well, it's actually written in Clojure) and it appears to get invoked 3 times every time I run it.

My function runs successfully and well within the timeout (which is set to the max of 5 minutes). It returns a string which I can see output when I test the function in the console.

I've seen some stuff online about having to call some Context success / done function but can't see that in the Java SDK (seems to be for Node only?).

Am I missing something?

This does not occur when I click test in the console (it only runs once) but does happen when triggered via a CloudWatch Trigger or running via the AWS SDK.

Thanks,

Donovan

Update: apologies, this does not happen when running via the trigger, only via the SDK and CLI, so perhaps there is some timeout in the call I am making.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For future reference for anyone else, the issue was the SDK and CLI hitting the read timeout of one minute and then retrying the request. I manually set this to 5 minutes to match my AWS Lambda timeout.

This can be done in the CLI by adding `--cli-read-timeout int` where `int` is your desired timeout (or simply `--cli-read-timeout 0` which disables the timeout altogether).

In the Java SDK it can be done by calling `setSocketTimeout(int socketTimeout)` on the `ClientConfiguration` object

In Clojure using Amazonica, add `:client-config {:socket-timeout xxx}` to your credentials map.

Comment: I solved this with `invokeRequest.setSdkRequestTimeout(180001);
                  invokeRequest.setSdkClientExecutionTimeout(180001);`

Comment: I was hoping the SDK would be smart enough to assume the timeout of the service it was connected to, so for lambda, if my timeout is 5 minutes, the SDK should adapt. Unfortunately not the case...lost many hours on this, but super thankful for this answer.