# AWS Lambda throwing ReadTimeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout

I need to invoke a lambda function once (with no retry).
That lambda take up to 5/10 minutes to execute.

I found multiple posts about timeouts and tried each one without success

```java
try {
    InvokeRequest invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest()
        .withFunctionName("mylambdaname")
        .withPayload(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload));

    //invokeRequest.setSdkRequestTimeout(0);
    //invokeRequest.setSdkClientExecutionTimeout(0);
    //invokeRequest.withSdkRequestTimeout(0);
    //invokeRequest.withSdkClientExecutionTimeout(0);

    AWSLambda awsLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(new EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper())
        .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
        .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration()
            //.withConnectionTimeout(0)
            //.withRequestTimeout(0)
            //.withClientExecutionTimeout(0)
            //.withSocketTimeout(0)
            .withMaxErrorRetry(0)
        ).build();

    awsLambda.invoke(invokeRequest);
} catch (ServiceException | JsonProcessingException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Setting up timeouts (like 15*60*1000) or none (0) still triggers a `ReadTimeout` after exactly one minute.
I also tried to install SDK v2 from AWS and the same problem shows up.

Tried examples :

- [AWS Lambda timeout when another (long) Lambda is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898894/aws-lambda-timeout-when-another-long-lambda-is-invoked)
- [How to increase the timeout for AWS Lambda client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379881/how-to-increase-the-timeout-for-aws-lambda-client)
- [AWS Lambda Java function invoked multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615009/aws-lambda-java-function-invoked-multiple-times)

PS: The lambda does work if the long task is shorten, so it's all about timeouts here

Full stacktrace

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:457)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1095)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$200(SSLSocketImpl.java:72)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:815)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
> at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
> at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
> at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:82)
> at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
> at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1074)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
> at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.doInvoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:2682)
> at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.invoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:2651)
> at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.invoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:2640)
> at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.executeInvoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:1503)
> at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.invoke(AWSLambdaClient.java:1474)
> at Repository.invokeLambda(Repository.java:60)
> at Service.invoke(Service.java:40)
> at Controller.invoke(Controller.java:37)
> at Controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9d602606.invoke()

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace?

Comment: @mattfreake provided it :)

Comment: Setting SocketTimeout at 0 does not leave a stacktrace, the lambda fails without expected logs after exactly one minute (timeout), but doesn't throw such Exception

Comment: Are you invoking the Lambda from a Spring Controller based on some HTTP request and do you want to return the response of the Lambda invocation in the HTTP response? If not, can you describe how you are invoking the Lambda?

Comment: @GSSwain the lambda is invoked from a SpringController, the context is sent to the controller the result isn't returned. However if the request fails, I have to return a 5xx (error is caught and thrown)

Comment: Can you share the exact version of Spring Boot, AWS SDK. I tried with aws-sdk 1.11.1010 and spring boot 2.4.5 and spring cloud Hoxton.SR11 worked fine with a function taking 14 minutes of time. If you could create a git repo, that would be great.

Comment: Agree - if you create a GIT instance. the community can def help you trouble shoot better. My recommendation here is to stop using Java V1 and move to V2. (using V2 is much better practice)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not authorized to share the project.
We use SpringBoot 2.2.6.RELEASE, SpringCloud Hoxton.SR6 and SDK com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:1.11.415 (and JavaSE 8).

I will try using SB 2.4.5, Hoxton SR11 and software.amazon.awssdk:1.11.1010
I don't know why our current dependency is com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda tbh

Comment: @smac2020 as mentionned "also tried to install SDK v2 from AWS and the same problem shows up.", I couldn't find any related post using v2 that's why I kept it up with v1

Comment: @GSSwain SpringCloud SR11 is incompatible with SpringBoot 2.4.x  
Tried so far with SB 2.3.10.RELEASE and SC SR11 and the same problem still shows up :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is worked for me, the timeout value set to 15 minutes:

```
AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard().withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration().withSocketTimeout(900000))
```

can you check the default lambda timeout value on AWS? AWS -> Lambda -> your function -> Change the Timeout setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These methods should do the trick which I saw that you have commented out:

- `setSDKRequestTimeout(int milliseconds)`
- `setSdkClientExecutionTimeout(int milliseconds)`

I don't think you're supposed to use 0. You should use `15*60*1000`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest.html#setSdkRequestTimeout-int-

Comment: The comments are methods I've already tried out. I know these methods should do the trick but none of them does. It might be due to SB/SC/SDK versions

Comment: Also 0 does force "no timeout" and should keep everything up until the end of a sync execution.
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615009/aws-lambda-java-function-invoked-multiple-times : "(or simply --cli-read-timeout 0 which disables the timeout altogether)"